# How to define lists in python dot env file?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, python-dotenv

In Fast API documentation it is recommended to use .env to load the config. Only that it only supports string as far as I understand it.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseSettings


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    api_tokens = []

    class Config:
        env_file = ".env"


settings = Settings()
app = FastAPI()
```

I usually change the API tokens every few months, by adding a new one to the list and after some time I remove the older ones.  That gives the users enough time to upgrade to latest edition without any disruption. In the meanwhile both API tokens will be valid for some time.

But I can't define a list in the `.env` file.

```
API_TOKENS = abc123,abc321
```

Am I missing something?

UPDATE:

It actually is possible.
The answer below is correct, however I still had to change the type like this:

```
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    api_tokens: list
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work,

```
API_TOKENS = ["abc123","abc321"]
```

Comment: Thanks, what do you put as type for ```api_tokens = []``` because this is still failing for me.

Comment: I didn't change any code at all. Changing `.env` file work for me, and it should. Because this is some kind of weird (oh!!) syntax of *dotenv* package

Comment: I added an update to the question how I solved it. Because if I leave the type as `str` I get this instead: `"api_tokens":"[\"abc123\",\"abc321\"]"`.

Comment: Just for those who are using nested Config this won't work, since there is a bug in pydantic https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/3971

Answer (score 4):

You can use json module to convert string variable to a list in python.

.env file

```
LIST_VAR='["Foo", "bar"]'
```

Python code

```
import os
import json
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
list_var = json.loads(os.environ['LIST_VAR'])
```